Is there a problem with ShareCount in LinkedIn's Time-Bound Organisations Share Statistics?
The ShareCount of all my scenarios I set up with Make retrieves 0 although there have been more than 60 Shares within a month.
Please see the API request and response for this execution:
{ "response": { "status": 200, "headers": { "content-type": "application/json", "x-restli-protocol-version": "2.0.0", "date": "Wed, 04 Sep 2024 09:55:37 GMT", "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "x-li-fabric": "prod-lva1", "x-li-pop": "prod-lva1-x", "x-li-proto": "http/1.1", "x-li-uuid": "AAYhSC0LExRs4E0SXkRVTQ==", "set-cookie": [ "bcookie=\"v=2&e5428570-9afa-4259-8910-22c564580ed0\"; Domain=.linkedin.com; Expires=Thu, 04-Sep-2025 09:55:37 GMT; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None", "li_gc=MTswOzE3MjU0NDM3Mzc7MjswMjGeXkSlUlz6LxzuKQ7pUIgN1kynhVh/3zLFVZTBBMi29A==; Domain=.linkedin.com; Expires=Mon, 03 Mar 2025 09:55:37 GMT; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None", "lidc=\"b=VB62:s=V:r=V:a=V:p=V:g=5536:u=1006:x=1:i=1725443737:t=1725527554:v=2:sig=AQF-ArvhtkYngwXQJAFbv1ERfjmEVsj7\"" ], "x-li-route-key": "\"b=VB62:s=V:r=V:a=V:p=V:g=5536:u=1006:x=1:i=1725443737:t=1725527554:v=2:sig=AQF-ArvhtkYngwXQJAFbv1ERfjmEVsj7\"" }, "body": { "paging": { "start": 0, "count": 10, "links": [], "total": 1 }, "elements": [ { "totalShareStatistics": { "uniqueImpressionsCount": 76029, "shareCount": 0, "engagement": 0.1109412821600579, "clickCount": 15255, "likeCount": 2492, "impressionCount": 160292, "commentCount": 36 }, "organizationalEntity": "urn:li:organization:11486116", "timeRange": { "start": 1722470400000, "end": 1725148800000 } } ] } }, "request": { "url": "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A11486116&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(end:1725228000000,start:1722549600000),timeGranularityType:MONTH)", "headers": { "user-agent": "Make/production", "authorization": "***", "linkedin-version": "202402", "x-restli-protocol-version": "2.0.0" }, "method": "GET" } }
Make support sent me to LinkedIn. Now I am here. #linkedin
